# ClickToFlash and H264 video not playing in 10.6

Tags: browser-addons, safari

ClickToFlash is a very useful plugin for Safari that prevents embedded flash movies from playing automatically.

http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/

However in SL there seems to be a problem with H264 video from YouTube.  Once the video is clicked, it displays the QuickTime player logo, but never loads the video.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: 1.4.2 or the 1.5fc2 version?

Comment: Also, give us the Youtube video link? :) I'm gonna install ClickToFlash and try it out for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the issue is not with Click To Flash, but with YouTube. For that particular video YouTube has not yet, or maybe never will create the h264 file. From what I have noticed this happens especially on new videos, at which point you click the little gear icon and just load the flash and everything works as expected.

Sometimes it may take a little longer for Quicktime to begin buffering depending on what mirror the video is being pulled down from which could also add to the delay you are seeing.

Answer (score -1):

32-bit plugins does not seems to work with SL Safari right now (because Safari defaults in 64bit mode).

Go to your Applications folder, right-click Safari, choose Get Info, and choose Open in 32-bit mode. See if it works.

Comment: 32 bit plugins work just perfectly fine with Snow Leopard. They get loaded into their own separate process. Click to Flash works perfectly on my system running the default Safari. This is not a plugin issue.

Comment: Okay if you say so - the web is awash with users crying "My plugin broke! Switch back to 32-bit to get it working!". Do give that a shot though.

Comment: I've just verified - Click2Flash doesn't work in Safari 64 bit. If you click on the "Safari" menu bar - there should be a ClickToFlash menu icon there - it disappears in 64bit mode, but re-appears in 32bit mode.

Comment: scoopdreams: Most "plugins" for Safari as people know them are Input Managers which don't work with 64-bit applications. The latest ClickToFlash works fine with 64-bit Safari. (1.5 betas or final candidates)

Comment: @Chealion - funny, the menu bar icon never did appear in Safari 64, I was using the 1.5fc2 version too. Never used that plugin before so no idea whether it worked or not - i just based it off the menu listing appearing or not.

Comment: @Chealion - wait, I'm also running the 64-bit kernel, would that have something to do with it?

Comment: @scoopdreams: I am running the 64-bit kernel, and when I click Safari I see a menu option called ClickToFlash from which I can select a few different options.

Comment: @scoopdreams: http://bit.ly/I2JZs

Comment: @scoopdreams: Ah, figured it out. When Safari is first loaded the plugin is not automatically loaded (because it is not needed). Go to YouTube.com or some other place where Flash is required, and then check Safari -> Click To Flash. It should now be visible.

Comment: Oh! -laughs- okay, thanks. That cleared things up - thought my SL install was wonky or something.